# Convert a 2D array into an Armadillo matrix (mat) object

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

How do I convert a standard C++ 2D array into an Armadillo `mat` object representing a matrix, so that I can perform matrix operations?

For example, I want to convert from:

```cpp
double a[10][20];
```

to:

```cpp
arma::mat A;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
arma::mat A(&a[0][0], 10, 20);
```

if you want a copy of the buffer and:

```
arma::mat A(&a[0][0], 10, 20, false);
```

if you want to use the buffer pointed out by `a`, for more detailed information see http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat

Comment: Thank you so much it works!!!
is there a way that we can reverse this process, meaning converting mat to 2d array?

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if you are satisfied. You can access the raw buffer from an arma matrix by using  double ptr*=A.memptr(), note that armadillo uses column-major ordering for matrixes.